# Adding more stop words in R

Tags: r, lda, stop-words

Presently, I'm using the function `CreateDtm()` in `R` to fit LDA model. In addition to the default stop words, I want to add my own words which are supposed to be removed.

```
library(textmineR)
myStopwords <- c("aa", "bb")
dtm <- CreateDtm(doc_vec = data$text,doc_names = data$id,
              stopword_vec = c(stopwords::stopwords("en"),
              stopwords::stopwords(source = "smart"))
```

Can one help me on how to add my own stop words in the above code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your own list to the list of existing stopwords. You are already combining two stopword lists. You can add at third one without any problem:

```
library(textmineR)
myStopwords <- c("aa", "bb")
dtm <- CreateDtm(doc_vec = data$text,doc_names = data$id,
              stopword_vec = c(stopwords::stopwords("en"),
              stopwords::stopwords(source = "smart"), myStopwords))
```